# Declaring methods for a javascript file in TypeScript:

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to import the masked input jQuery plu gin and be able to view the intellisense within our typescript files. From my understanding, all I need to is create a definition file and reference the said definition file with my typescript file.

Right now, I just want a single method where I can do the following:

```
$("#date").mask("99/99/9999");
```

Accordingly, I created a maskedinput.d.ts file as such:

```
declare interface maskedInput extends JQuery{
    mask(string) : void;
 };
```

however, this doesn't seem to do the trick. In my ts file, when I start typing

```
$('#some-id').
```

I get no intellisense for the method mask. What am I missing here?

Comment: As Ryan said. Basically $ has the interface type of JQuery. Creating a new interface does not change that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this instead (interfaces are open):

```
interface JQuery {
    mask(string): void;
}
```

TypeScript doesn't automatically change the type of a `$('...')` expression to `maskedInput` just because there's some interface out there that happens to extend `JQuery`.